# Signup using invitation mail

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

Can we send a magic link for signup via Azure AD B2C policy rather than the application sending it? The sample at https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite shows the app sending the B2C signup link.

Comment: I have implemented a very similar solution based partially on the provided example, so can confirm that B2C does have this capability.

Comment: It should be possible. Please take a look at this link: https://contos.io/magic-signin-invitation-mails-in-azure-ad-b2c-2fb5c825d0e1.

Comment: Hi, The link is sending the email via app. Can a B2C page send the signup link via mail?